ragged2e: forbid overlong lines
I am trying to set some text ragged-right with ragged2e. To conform to the format I'm working with, my text absolutely must not go over the right margin under any circumstances.
LaTeX sometimes decides to do this anyway, although it produces an overfull hbox warning.
How can I tell LaTeX to never, ever make an overlong line - I'm fine with as much white space as necessary at the end of a line to put the offending word or formula on the next line?
(I presume I need to turn off whatever is also causing a badness of 10000 for making a line break "too early", but I don't know how to do this.)
EDIT: MWE from my system - the word 'might' on the third line causes a 2.6pt overfull hbox, what I'd need is a linebreak before that word never mind if line 3 gets a bit short (and without needing to do an explicit \linebreak).
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  a4paper,
  left=20mm,
  right=50mm,
  voffset=5mm,
  textwidth=190mm,
  marginparwidth=0mm,
  top=20mm,
  bottom=25mm
}

\usepackage[default]{opensans}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[document,raggedrightboxes]{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

A set is the mathematician's answer whenever you have a question that can have
zero, one, or more than one correct answers. Imagine you are writing an equation-
solving procedure in a program, depending on your programming language this might
also be called a method, or a function, or something else.

\end{document}

Here is what I get (red line added manually to show the problem):


If you use the standard \raggedright instead of  \RaggedRight from ragged2e  you will only get overfull boxes if something is too bg, if you have \includegraphics[width=2\textwidth]{...] then the image will make an overfull box and you can't really avoid that.

Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue?

Example added. Jose: I think that question is about block text, not ragged-right text?

Unrelated yo your problem, but your geometry settings give the following warning: Over-specification in h'-direction.` You don't have to specify all values. E.g. if you set the margins, geometry will calculate the text width so that everything fits your page.

(instead of manually adding a red line, you could use the showframe option of geometry)

as David wrote: do not use the ragged2e package if you never want a overfull line.

The advice I was given was "if you want ragged, use ragged2e as it makes better hyphenation than the default". I'll experiment with the other version too, though.

@Holly It does. Generally speaking, that's reasonable advice. But, in your case, the overriding consideration it to avoid overfull hboxes. For that particular aim, the standard \raggedright will do better. Or maybe what you want to ask is 'how can I absolutely forbid overlong lines while allowing hyphenation?'

Thanks for the advice, everyone. I've removed ragged2e and am manually fixing up any breaking layout changes that produced.
